# Sencha Touch: Ext.Map within TabPanel

Tags: google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch, tabpanel

I'm quite new to sencha touch. The goal is to create an app which has a TabPanel containing four Tabs, one of them should be a map (the others are a NestedList and two Panels working like a charm). I've tried to make the map card like

```
NPApp.views.Mapcard = Ext.extend(Ext.Map, { ...
```

where I ended up with getting really strange results like some views are overlapping and no map is shown.

The second try was to creating a Panel, embed it into the TabPanel and add a map to the panel, where I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROADMAP' of undefined;
> sencha-touch-debug.js:24840

I've already tried to change the mapType to google.map.MapTypeID like mentioned in the Google Map API V3, no success there.

I just can't get the hang on it, hope you can give me some hints!

The App:

```
NPApp = new Ext.Application({
    name: "NPApp",
    title: "NextPuff",
    icon: 'images/icon.png',
    tabletStartupScreen: 'images/index_default.jpg',
    phoneStartupScreen: 'images/index_default.jpg',
    
    launch: function() {
        this.views.viewport = new this.views.Viewport();
        this.views.homecard = this.views.viewport.getComponent('navi');
    }

});
```

The Viewport:

```
NPApp.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    store: NPApp.npstore,


    initComponent: function() {


        Ext.apply(this, {
            tabBar: {
                dock: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                }
            },
            items: [
                { xtype: 'homecard', stretch: true},
                { xtype: 'searchcard', id: 'navi' },
        { xtype: 'mapcard' },
                { xtype: 'morecard' }
            ]
        });
        NPApp.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

The Mapcard:

```
NPApp.views.Mapcard = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    title: "Map",
    iconCls: "map",


    initComponent: function() {
        var npMap = new Ext.Map({
            title: 'Map',
            useCurrentLocation: true,
            listeners: {
                centerchange : function(comp, map){
                //    refreshMap(map);
                }
           },
            mapOptions : {
                mapTypeControl : false,
                navigationControl : false,
                streetViewControl : false,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                zoom: 17,
                draggable: false,
                keyboardShortcuts: false,
                scrollwheel: false
           }
        });
        Ext.apply(this, {
            defaults: {
                styleHtmlContent: true
            },
                items: [npMap]
        });
        NPApp.views.Homecard.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});


Ext.reg('mapcard', NPApp.views.Mapcard);
```

Sencha 1.1.0; Google JavaScript Maps API V3; Safari 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar application running. Your tabpanel is perfect. All you need to alter is your map code.... Try this instead :

```
var map = new Ext.Map({
        mapOptions : {
            center : center,
            zoom : 20,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                }
        },

        listeners : {
            maprender : function(comp, map){

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: center,
                     //title : 'Sencha HQ',
                     map: map
                });
                setTimeout( function(){map.panTo (center);} , 1000);
            }

        },

         geo:new Ext.util.GeoLocation({
              autoUpdate:true,
              maximumAge: 0,
              timeout:2000,
              listeners:{
                locationupdate: function(geo) {
                  center = new google.maps.LatLng(geo.latitude, geo.longitude);
                  if (map.rendered)
                    map.update(center)
                  else
                    map.on('activate', map.onUpdate, map, {single: true, data: center});
                },
                 locationerror: function (   geo,
                                            bTimeout, 
                                            bPermissionDenied, 
                                            bLocationUnavailable, 
                                            message) {
                    if(bLocationUnavailable){
                        alert('Your Current Location is Unavailable on this device');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('Error occurred.');
                    }      
                 }
              }
         })

  });
```

This creates the map object and sets the center to ur current location. Now you need to dock this object inside an Ext.extend(Ext.Panel({}) object. Ive tried directly creating the map object but it needs a panel to display on.

So you're panel code should go something like so:

```
NPApp.views.Mapcard = new Ext.extend(Ext.Panel({
        iconCls : 'map',
        title : 'Map',

        layout: 'card',
        ui: 'light',
        items: [map],
        listeners:{
        }            
    });
)
```

It took me ages of going thru a dozen or more examples to make the current location work. This is a combination of several codes and a bunch of stuff in the Google API.

Lemme know if you have any more questions about Google Maps or directions.

Cheers :)
Sasha